# Can I cut this circuit board trace and still use the board OK?

Tags: pcb

I have a device that I would like to modify by removing a button. I thought initially that the button was wired to a smaller board but it seems the board is made specifically for this and has a trace going to the button instead of using a wire. So would it be possible to cut this part of the board, through the trace, removing the button and that portion of the board without issues? This isn't simply to remove the button, I need to make this fit into something and this button is physically in the way.

[image: Cut through this trace]

Comment: What's the device? And are there any components on the far side?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to user107063's answer :

- check if the button is normally open or normally closed. If it is normally open, then cutting the trace is the same as not using the button. If it is normally closed, then cutting the trace is the same as pressing the button (might be a problem or not)
- if you cut the PCB, you are also separating the 2 ground planes (above and bellow the trace going to the switch). Check that there is at least one other connection somewhere (I expect there is one, otherwise there should have been a wider path between the 2 planes, which would have been trivial to do)
- make sure you cut properly enough to avoid creating short circuits. If need be, remove the "extra" copper from the track (and near the track) with a knife or a cutter

Answer (score 1):

If the trace leads nowhere else but the button, you should likely be fine (whether the trace is open-ended in the button itself or with an open trace should be pretty equivalent).

However, the way the trace is enclosed by ground, you have to make extra sure that you don't end with the trace shorted to ground accidentally after making the cut: the cut copper layers may well touch.

You also should pick a tool for cutting that will not affect the rest of the board.  Any kind of saw should be using extra-fine teeth to avoid excessive vibration, and have the board well fixated.  One can use a patent knife instead but that's kind of tedious.